# How to create Comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have generic class, suppose

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T a;

    MyClass(T x) {
        a = x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return a.toString();
    }
}
```

I want to make Comparator to be able to sort collection filled with MyClass elements.

If I write it this way

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        return o1.a.compareTo(o2.a);
    }
}
```

I get warning Unchecked call ...

Will it be right to write comparator like

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<MyClass<T>> {
    public int compare(MyClass<T> o1, MyClass<T> o2) {
        return o1.a.compareTo(o2.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks right to me.  Does it work?

Comment: In your second block of code, you didn't put `implements Comparator<MyClass<T>> {...`. I assume it was your typo?

Comment: yes it works. It's just I'm newbie to generics

Comment: Yeah, then it's fine.  The only thing you're missing is something to deal with the case where `a` is `null`.  That applies to your `toString` method as well as to your comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `MyClass` to be `Comparable` so you can sort without passing in a `Comparator` that could be done with something like,

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements
        Comparable<MyClass<T>> {
    T a;

    MyClass(T x) {
        a = x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (a == null) return "null";
        return a.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass<T> o) {
        if (this.a == null) {
            if (o == null || o.a == null) return 0;
            return -1;
        } else if (o == null || o.a == null) return 1;
        return this.a.compareTo(o.a);
    }
}
```

If you really did want to create a `MyClassComparator` then it should look something like,

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T a;

    MyClass(T x) {
        a = x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (a == null) return "null";
        return a.toString();
    }
}

public class MyClassComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements
        Comparator<MyClass<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass<T> left, MyClass<T> right) {
        if (left == null) {
            if (right == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        } else if (right == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (left.a == null) {
            if (right.a == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        } else if (right.a == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return left.a.compareTo(right.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidWallace Then it fails fast.

Comment: OK, so your answer is "yes", then?

Comment: @DavidWallace Edited to handle `null`(s).